# How difficult is it to go from Blum Tandem Plus to the Blum Legrabox drawer system for a DIY cabinet maker

Tags: drawer, drawer-construction, hardware

I built a couple dozen Blum "Tandem Plus" kitchen drawers many years ago (3/4" prefinished maple), with the grey metal sides and they were relatively easy to build and install.

Now it's time to build a bunch of built-in vanity drawers and I planned on using Tandem Plus, but the parts seem to be much harder to find, plus I see a couple things that I like about the new Blum line, Legrabox.

I don't build cabinets very often and I'm curious if it's much of a leap in difficulty to switch to Blum Legrabox for this batch of drawers.

Blum recommends a jig for drilling the drawer pieces, but I don't think I'll need that since I'm using plywood. I didn't use any jig to build the Tandembox drawers. It seems like slide mounting would be similar. Building the drawers looks straight-forward.

I haven't found any videos about mounting the runners for a DIY. I'm trying to avoid surprises.

Comment: I think you'd be best asking this on a regular woodworking forum with an active pro membership, where you're more likely to find users of various Blum products. If you're lucky you'll find there's more than one user of the Legrabox system or something else/similar that they'll recommend instead.

Comment: Level of difficulty is a matter of opinion and skill

Comment: It's what you're used to and have experience with. Each time it gets easier. If all you have is manufacturer recommendations it would probably best to consider following them. Did you reach out to Blum? They may have media/materials to help you.

Comment: Also, just glancing quickly, [Legrabox](https://www.blum.com/us/en/products/boxsystems/legrabox/programme/)  seems to be drawer boxes and integrated slides... not just slides so the application is going to be entirely different. You won't be building drawer boxes out of plywood.

Comment: Welcome to WSE.  As several comments have hinted, this question is not a good fit with our format and experience and will be closed soon.  I do encourage you to participate and take the [tour](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about what we are about.